# Make mockito force method to return its value before process finish

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

Is there a way to make mock or spy object from mockito to return its value before the method compete? for example if I have class like this

```
public class Calculator{

    public List calculate(List l){
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        method1(l);
        method2(l);
        method3(l);

        return l;
    }

    public void method1(List l){
        //calculate something here
    }

    public void method2(List l){
        //calculate something here
    }

    public void method3(List l){
        //calculate something here
    }
}
```

Then I use spy like this

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
Calculator spy = spy(calculator);
when(spy.calculate(aList)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Can I make the method to end its process after method2 called? I know I can use `doNothing().when(spy).method3(anyList())` to avoid method3 being called, but is there any way to make method calculate to stop its process after method 2 is called?

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do this in a unit test? Could you add some more context as this seems like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: because my real method is a method to calculate multiple entity in the database, some earlier calculating process can be done without using database, But the later process will need to update or select from database. I want my code coverage in this method, but the author is other people, so if i can i want to keep the method as its now while still maintain the code coverage in some of it.

Comment: Instead of having `method1` and `method2` produce _side effects_ on `List l`, could you refactor them to _return_ the calculation results? That way, you could simply unit-test those two methods individually.

Comment: thats true that i can refactor those method, but the real method is so complex and if i can, i dont want to make change in a stable system, as i mention it before "but the author is other people, so if i can i want to keep the method as its now while still maintain the code coverage in some of it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question directly: No, you can't use Mockito to avoid method calls entirely or otherwise deeply change the behavior of a system-under-test.

Internally, Mockito creates a dynamic subclass* of the class in question. This correctly implies that unless you override `Calculator.calculate` (defeating the purpose of testing `calculate`'s real implementation) you will not be able to use Mockito to avoid calling `method3`.

Your best options:

- Refactor as discussed in the comments.
- Use `doNothing().when(spiedCalculator).method3()` as you suggested.
- Throw an exception in `method2` that avoids the call to `method3`, though this prevents flow from reaching the part of the function after `method3`.

---

*The implementation is actually a generated-bytecode proxy class made with CGLib or ByteBuddy.